# How many $k$-nary relations are there for sets $A_i$ to $A_k$ of sizes $s_i$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I found lots of questions for binary relations. I wonder what the generalization would look like. I somehow can't seem to wrap my hand around this. Any suggestions?

/edit: For my particular case the question is, given a set $A$ with $n$ elemements, how many $k$-nary relations are there, so in this case every $s_i=n$. But I find the generalization a bit more interesting.

/edit: would it  be something like $k^{s_1 \cdot s_2 \cdot  s_3 \cdot \ldots\cdot s_k}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is a function in the form $A_1 × A_2 × A_3 × \ldots × A_k \to \{\text{true},\text{false}\}$. So there are $s_1\cdot s_2\cdot s_3\cdot\ldots\cdot s_k$ combinations of elements which may or may not be in relation. And you can decide whether or not a combination is in relation or not for each combination independently. So you have $2^{s_1\cdot s_2\cdot s_3\cdot\ldots\cdot s_k}$ relations in total.